# Why is json_encode returning arrays instead of objects?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

If you are inclined to downvote this question, please indicate the reason so I can learn from my mistakes.

**PHP - EDIT**

```
<?php

require_once "dbconnect.php";

function isEmpty($str) {
    return strlen(trim($str)) == 0;
}

function getWritersData() {
    try {
        if (!isset($_REQUEST["userid"]) || isEmpty($_REQUEST["userid"])) {
            throw new Exception('A user-id must be supplied.');       
        }
        $userid = $_REQUEST["userid"];
        $dbh = connect2DB();
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Title, WorkType, FormType, Genre, NumberOfPages, Filename, OriginalFilename FROM Writers WHERE fkAccounts = :userid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($rows, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'General error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}    
/** Update writers data **/
function saveWritersData() 
{
    try {
        include_once "commonWritersPostElements";
        $dbh = connect2DB();
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Writers SET fkAccounts=:userid, Title=:title, WorkType=:worktype, FormType=:formtype, Genre=:genre, NumberOfPages=:pages, Filename=:filename, OriginalFilename=:origonal WHERE fkAccounts=:userid");
        $worktype = "1";            
        $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $stmt->bindParam(':worktype', $worktype, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $stmt->bindParam(':formtype', $formtype, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genre', $genre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pages', $nbrPages, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
        $stmt->bindParam(':filename', $NewFileName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $stmt->bindParam(':original', $File_Name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);        
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'General error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}    
function deleteWritersData() 
{
    try {
        if (!isset($_REQUEST["userid"]) || isEmpty($_REQUEST["userid"]))
            throw new Exception('user-id is missing.');       
        else {
            $userid = filter_var(trim($_REQUEST["user-id"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($userid, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
        $dbh = connect2DB();
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE Writers WHERE fkAccounts=:userid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'General error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}    


if (!isset($_REQUEST['action'])  || isEmpty($_REQUEST['action']))
    throw new Exception('Programmer error: action not posted.');
else {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'get-writer-data':
        getWritersData();
        break;
    case 'update-writers':
        select();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown action: " . $action);
        break;
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['action'])  || isEmpty($_REQUEST['action']))
    throw new Exception('Programmer error: action not posted.');
else {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'get-writer-data':
        getWritersData();
        break;
    case 'delete-writers':
        deleteWritersData();
        break;
    case 'update-writers':
        saveWritersData();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown action: " . $action);
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    populateWritersDropdowns();

    data = {};
    data.action = 'get-writer-data';
    data.userid = sessionStorage.getItem("user-id");
    console.log("user-id-manage-uploads=" + sessionStorage.getItem("user-id"))
    ajax('post', 'php/manage-uploads.php', data, getSuccess, "Error retrieving writer's data: ");
    $(".tr-clone");
    function getSuccess(data) {
        console.log("data=" + data);
        var trClone = $(".tr-clone");
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        var count = 0;
        for (var key in jsonData) count++
        $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
            trClone.find(".title").val(value.Title);
            trClone.find(".work-type").val(value.WorkType);
            trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
            trClone.find(".genre").val(value.Genre);
            console.log("value.FormType=" + value.FormType + ", form-type.val()=" + trClone.find(".form-type").val());
            console.log("value.Genre=" + value.Genre + ", genre.val()=" + trClone.find(".genre").val());
            trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
            trClone.find(".nbr-pages").val(value.NumberOfPages);
            trClone.find(".synopsis a[href='" + value.Filename + "']");
            if (key === count - 1) return false;
            trClone = trClone.clone().insertAfter($(".tr-clone:last"));
        });
    }
```

**console.log**

In the JS code, the JSON.parse(...) throws the error show below.

> data=[{"Title":"Mozart, Wunderkind","0":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind","WorkType":"1","1":"1","FormType":"4","2":"4","Genre":"12","3":"12","NumberOfPages":"250","4":"250","Filename":"6532744220.pdf","5":"6532744220.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"},{"Title":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind Query-Letter","0":"Mozart, Wunderkind
>   Query-Letter","WorkType":"2","1":"2","FormType":"7","2":"7","Genre":"9","3":"9","NumberOfPages":"129","4":"129","Filename":"9981287843.pdf","5":"9981287843.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"}][{"Title":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind","0":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind","WorkType":"1","1":"1","FormType":"4","2":"4","Genre":"12","3":"12","NumberOfPages":"250","4":"250","Filename":"6532744220.pdf","5":"6532744220.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"},{"Title":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind Query-Letter","0":"Mozart, Wunderkind
>   Query-Letter","WorkType":"2","1":"2","FormType":"7","2":"7","Genre":"9","3":"9","NumberOfPages":"129","4":"129","Filename":"9981287843.pdf","5":"9981287843.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"}]
>
> VM1161:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position
>   613n.parseJSON @ jquery.min.js:4getSuccess @ VM1137:13(anonymous
>   function) @ VM1136:97j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2x
>   @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: This is not mandatory that always `json_encode` returns Object, Try this `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as second parameter of `json_encode`.

Comment: Your JSON string is not properly formatted that is why it is throwing this error, would you paste your json string, so that I can get idea what is wrong with it...

Comment: @ron: on the first look of your error it seems like you are appending two json string and sending it as response to the client, which you shouldn't

Comment: It's an array of objects, as indicated by `[{...}, {...}, ...]` - Just like your php variable. fetchAll returns an array of objects aswell. See the documentation of [fetchall](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and [fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: @Paraq - the JSON string is shown in the console.log.

Comment: @Paraq - How could it be that I am appending two strings? There are two rows returned from the query.

Comment: the Json you are showing is actually twice the same: `[{...data}][{..samedata}]`. And that's the problem! It looks like somewhere you've double-output that json.

Comment: @rontornambe: yahh it is incorrect ... look closely at this part <<<Letter.pd"}][{"Title":"Mozart>>> ... here ther should be comma between square brackets ... so it should be <<<Letter.pd"}],[{"Title":"Mozart>>>... and whole JSON string should be in another sqare bracket ...

Comment: You are echoing your  `echo json_encode($rows);` twice. Are you doing `getWritersData() ` in a loop?

Comment: @Frayne - I tried that but still get an error. Now there are two objects returned but they are not separated by a comma, which gives weight to Paraq's comment about returning .two strings

Comment: so yahh you are echoing data two times, so your whole JSON is sent wrong to the client

Comment: @rontornambe : please show your full php code

Comment: The complete PHP code is now posted.

Comment: Is that really the original php-code? because you have twice the same code in there.... that would make sense why it's posting the json twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here closely looking at your JSON string I came to know that you are echoing the string two times ... so that it is sent to the client two times appended, and that is why it is not shown in correct  way...

You can use [JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) online tool to get idea about your JSON strings .... So you need to figure out in your php code, that why it is being sent two times, it must be something like you have echoed it twice... if you put your whole php code then we could help you more..

So all n all, you need to correct your response from the server, as JSON encoding is working fine and that encoded string should be responded only once

BINGO !!!! in your php code you are executing switch case twice after line if (!isset($_REQUEST['action'])  || isEmpty($_REQUEST['action'])) , see below that is why it is echoing twice ... and spoils your JSON string

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['action'])  || isEmpty($_REQUEST['action']))
    throw new Exception('Programmer error: action not posted.');
else {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'get-writer-data':
        getWritersData();
        break;
    case 'update-writers':
        select();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown action: " . $action);
        break;
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['action'])  || isEmpty($_REQUEST['action']))
    throw new Exception('Programmer error: action not posted.');
else {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch($action) {
    case 'get-writer-data':
        getWritersData();
        break;
    case 'delete-writers':
        deleteWritersData();
        break;
    case 'update-writers':
        saveWritersData();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown action: " . $action);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Paraqq. I agree that it appears that I am echoing twice, but I cannot fro the life of me understand where that can be happening from the PHP function.